# Função contar esquerda arvore

Tags: c

Essa função abaixo compila corretamente, funciona.

```
int qtd_niveis (tipo_arvore * raiz)
{
if (raiz == NULL)
    return 0;
int esquerda = qtd_niveis(raiz -> esq);
int direita = qtd_niveis(raiz -> dir);
if (esquerda > direita)
    return ++ esquerda;
return ++ direita;
}
```

Tentei algo assim:

```
int qtd_niveis_esq (tipo_arvore * raiz)
{
if (raiz == NULL)
    return 0;
int esquerda = qtd_niveis_esq(raiz -> esq);
if (esquerda > direita)
    return ++ esquerda;    
}`
```

Só que não me retorna o quantidade de níveis correta da esquerda. alguém poderia a me ajudar a achar onde está o erro.
Obrigado

Comment: Você quer a quantia de elementos a esquerda da raiz ou você quer obter o comprimento do ramo mais a esquerda da árvore? No código, aparentemente você está fazendo o segundo, mas algo me diz que você quer o primeiro.

Comment: Quero saber apenas quantos níveis possui a esquerda, o primeiro código retorna quantos níveis tem uma árvore, se tem 6 a esquerda e 7 a direita, vai me retornar 7, isso no primeiro código, e no segundo código, tem que me retornar por exemplo apenas 6.

Comment: Para ficar bem claro, nesta [imagem](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Sorted_binary_tree.svg/333px-Sorted_binary_tree.svg.png), quais elementos deveriam ser considerados? `FBA` por ser o ramo mais à esquerda ou `FBDC` por ser o maior à esquerda da raiz?

Comment: Elementos: `ABCDEF` (em_ordem )esquerda, tem que retornar 4 níveis. Se do lado direito tivesse mais níveis, por exemplo 5 níveis, não me interessaria. Me interessa apenas esquerda que é 4 níveis.

Comment: Algo [assim](https://ideone.com/CizCIL) funciona?

Comment: Aqui retornou `7`em vez de `4`

Comment: Acho que esse código seu está contando todos os níveis de cada lado, sendo no meu exemplo `4` da esquerda e `3` da direita, por isso `7`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58895/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-andre).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int
qtd_niveis_esq(tipo_arvore * raiz) {
    return 1 + qtd_niveis(raiz->esq);
}
```

O problema é que você só quer ignorar o filho direito **do nó raiz**. A partir do filho esquerdo da raiz, você quer usar o algoritmo normal de determinação da altura da árvore. A única diferença é que você tem que somar um por causa do nível que o nó raiz ocupa.

O código que você fez para `qtd_niveis_esq()` determina a altura *da folha mais à esquerda de todas* (aquela que seria visitada primeiro numa busca por profundidade), o que não é necessariamente a altura da sub-árvore esquerda (salvo coincidência).

EDIT: Aparentemente, a solução precisa ser recursiva?  Neste caso, podemos reimplementar a `qtd_niveis()` só para cumprir tabela:

```
static int
altura_aux(tipo_arvore * raiz) {
    int e, d;

    if (!raiz) return 0;
    e = altura_aux(raiz->esq);
    d = altura_aux(raiz->dir);

    return 1 + (e > d ? e : d);
}

int
qtd_niveis_esq(tipo_arvore * raiz) {
    return 1 + altura_aux(raiz->esq);
}
```

É escrever código à toa, mas agora a recursividade está (re)implementada.

Comment: Obrigado deu certinho aqui.

Comment: Problema é que você não usa recursividade no seu código, já o de cima usa, mas funcionou normal aqui.

Comment: Ele chama a `qtd_niveis()`, que é recursiva; mas de todos os modos, não há nada na pergunta que faça menção a recursividade.